# Maintaining a javascript "mirror" of your user object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Supposed you have a user who is logined, and has certain attributes - name, nickname, followers, etc which is stored in the backend

You would be using this attributes extensively in javascript display, and having a mirror object in javascript would be very helpful.

How would you do this? I am sure it is a very common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the js-data-helper plugin](http://github.com/CodeOfficer/js-data-helper), which gives you rails helpers that dump data attributes into DOM elements.

It hasn't been updated in a while, but it has lots of features and is well-documented. Also, if you want to go with a custom solution, you can get some pointers by seeing how it's done with this plugin.

Comment: this plugin looks great, although might be too complicated for my needs. but you are right, it is giving me a lot of the right ideas for designing a custom, simple version

Comment: Cool, just be careful about storing arrays and hashes. Those can be tricky to convert sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you could do it. Your application.js file could make an AJAX call to a User controller that returns `@current_user` serialized to JSON.

```
var currentUser;

var success = function(user) {
  currentUser = user;
}

$.get("/users/current/", success);
```

In your controller:

```
def current
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :json => @current_user }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a global hash collection, by placing some javascript in 'views/layouts/application.html.erb'.

That would be my guess =)

Comment: that is what i am doing now, but it is too hard to maintain and keep consistent